# Is the Dialogflow Payload Class deprecated? Custom Payload in dialogflow is not responding for Telegram

Tags: dialogflow-es-fulfillment

For the 'test intent', I have enabled the `Enable Webhook Call for this intent`
I have correctly setup Telegram integration to the bot.

In the fullfilment code, I am using the Constructor for Payload object(https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/fulfillment-library/rich-responses#new_payloadplatform_payload)and I have specified the string indicating target platform of payload. Please see in code below the welcome function:

```
    const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
    const {Text, Card, Image, Suggestion, Payload} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment'); 

    exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

    function test(agent) {
      agent.add(new Payload(agent.TELEGRAM, {

        "text": "Please click on button below to share your number",
        "reply_markup": {
          "one_time_keyboard": true,
          "resize_keyboard": true,
          "keyboard": [
            [
              {
                "text": "Share my phone number",
                "callback_data": "phone",
                "request_contact": true
              }
            ],
            [
              {
                "text": "Cancel",
                "callback_data": "Cancel"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
       }));
      }

      // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
      let intentMap = new Map();
      intentMap.set('test Intent', test);
      agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
       });
```

Dialogflow is not returning the payload response in the fulfillment code to telegram on invocation of the intent.
I have taken a look at the project function logs but their is no errors being logged.
**Their is no reason for my code not to work**

Is the payload class deprecated in dialogflow?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today and with this is running now

```
        var pl_tl = {
            "telegram": {
                "text": "Please click on button below to share your number",
                "reply_markup": {
                    "one_time_keyboard": true,
                    "resize_keyboard": true,
                    "keyboard": [
                        [
                            {
                                "text": "Share my phone number",
                                "callback_data": "phone",
            "request_contact": true
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            {
                                "text": "Cancel",
                                "callback_data": "Cancel"
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }   
        }


        let pl = new Payload(agent.TELEGRAM, pl_tl, { sendAsMessage: true, rawPayload: true });
```

Comment: the fulfillment response is returning this: 
`{
  "fulfillmentMessages": [],
  "outputContexts": []
}`. 
It did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The [dialogflow WebhookClient](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/fulfillment-library/webhook-client) used in the Dialogflow fulfillment webhook logic returns
an Express HTTP response object that contains the send method. I hooked into this method to send response back to dialogflow's webhook fulfillment API. See code below.

```
function telegramIntegration(agent) {

  const ClientResponse=
  {
    "ClientResponse": [
      {
        "payload": {
          "telegram": 
          {
            "text": "Please share your contact",
            "reply_markup": {
              "keyboard": [
                [
                  {
                    "text": "Share my phone number",
                    "callback_data": "phone",
                    "request_contact": true
                  }
                ],
                [
                  {
                    "text": "Cancel",
                    "callback_data": "Cancel"
                  }
                ]
              ],
              "one_time_keyboard": true,
              "resize_keyboard": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  response.send(JSON.stringify(ClientResponse));
}
```

However this work-around does not answer my question "**Is the Dialogflow Payload Class deprecated?**"